# Restricting permission to drop column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Client] ADD [Awesomness] [nvarchar](max)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Client] DROP COLUMN [Awesomness]
```

The second command I don't want to be successful, I don't want any `DROP COLUMN` to succeed. So I created a user for my database, just wondering how I can deny this user the permission to `DROP COLUMN`. I set up a trigger but that doesn't seem to take care of `DROP COLUMN`. Is there anyway I could restrict this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TR_DB_NO_DROPPING_OBJECTS_2]
on DATABASE
FOR 
DROP_PROCEDURE,DROP_FUNCTION,DROP_VIEW,DROP_TABLE, DROP_DEFAULT,DROP_EXTENDED_PROPERTY
AS
 BEGIN
    IF  --only two accounts allowed to drop stuff
   suser_name() NOT IN('test' )

 BEGIN
 --raise an error, which goes to the error log
 RAISERROR('Unauthorized use of drop object from inpermissible host.', 16, 1)
 --prevent the drop
  ROLLBACK
    END
 --if it got to here, it was the "right" user from the "right" machine (i hope)
 END
```

The roles I've assigned my user.

```
use Hasan
go
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'TestUser'
go

use Hasan
go
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'TestUser'
go

use Hasan
GO
GRANT EXECUTE TO [TestUser]
GO

use Hasan
GO
GRANT INSERT TO [TestUser]
GO

use Hasan
GO
GRANT SELECT TO [TestUser]
GO

use Hasan
GRANT ALTER TO [TestUser]
GO

use Hasan
GO
GRANT UPDATE TO [TestUser]
GO

use Hasan
GO
GRANT DELETE TO [TestUser]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be an Alter_Table DDL event.  See if that works for you.

Also, I am not sure if you have looked into roles.  Granting dbwriter and dbreader allows CRUD operations but no changes to DDL.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx

EDIT:
This example does not check for a user but it works on my test table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testtrig 
ON Database 
FOR alter_table 
AS 
    Declare @Msg nvarchar(max) = (SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)'))
     If @Msg Like '%Drop Column ColumnA%'
     Rollback
GO
```

There is probably a better way than parsing the message text like in my example, this was just a quick test.

Also remember this is just a safety to let the user know they should not drop this column.  If they have DDL rights they can disable or delete the trigger.

Comment: If I restrict Alter_Table event, wouldn't that also restrict `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Client] ADD [Awesomness] [nvarchar](max)` ? And Also I gave my user dbwriter and dbreader roles but the user can still drop columns.

Comment: I just created a test account and I am unable to drop a column if the account only has dbwriter and dbreader.  Your user must either have login setting like sysadmin or maybe part of a group that has rights needed.  As you said this would deny ability to add or drop columns, create tables / views etc.  Using the trigger with Alter_Table may be your best choice if you want to allow other DDL changes by the user.

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding Alter_Table in my trigger but can still drop columns..any thoughts on this?

Comment: Did you see my edit?  The code I added works for me.

Comment: I changed it to FOR ddl_database_level_events and it appears to be working.

Comment: for some reason I can still drop columns after I execute your code. I was wondering could it have anything to do with the roles I've assigned my user? Added them in the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114161/discussion-between-hasan-qureshi-and-joe-c).